# Replacing mysql with MariaDB

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, mariadb, phpmyadmin

[phpMyAdmin shows this version !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pgSg.png)

I am new to Linux and servers. I was using mysql 5.5 (was installed using third party repositories) as my DBMS and then I decided to replace it with the latest version of MariaDB.

I executed following commands to stop and delete the mysql:

```
service mysqld stop
yum -y remove mysql*
```

then I added MariaDB repositories for my OS (CentOS 6 - 64bit) to the yum. 
Installed it using:

```
yum install -y MariaDB-server MariaDB-client MariaDB-devel
```

started it with:

```
service mysql start
```

and it successfully started.

Then when I opened phpMyAdmin I recognized it is still connecting to mysql5.5 ! and also from php scripts it seems it is still connecting to that older mysql! I tried to stop mysqld but it told me there is no such service!

When I execute :

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.14-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

I am really confused. Can you please help me what happened and how can I fix it ?

Comment: mariadb is a fork from mysql

Comment: Yes I am aware of that . But the server version is not the same ! Please look at the picture I linked at top and the version I get with mysql -V

Comment: Perhaps phpMyAdmin was using cached values from your previous install?

Comment: @ThomasN if this is the case where can I delete the cached values ?

Comment: I would check the configuration values in `config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin isn't connecting to a service that doesn't exist. Assuming that `netstat -tulpn` shows that MariaDB is listening on port 3306, those scripts are reporting an incorrect version (As MariaDB is a MySQL fork) or a cached version (Look at Thomas N's comments).

If you want to be 100% sure, just perform a change in phpMyAdmin and use the `mysql` command line tool to connect to the MariaDB database and verify it changed.

Comment: It was fixed automatically. I did not do any change so I think it was cached.